# The ratio of upside deviation to downside deviation in portfolio weighting

Tags: risk, returns, asset-returns

I've been calling this ratio "acceleration" in my head, so I'll do the same in this post. The question is, is this relationship used anywhere and if so, how? My thought process is as follows.

Risk is typically quantified through standard deviation. But how good of a proxy for risk is SD really? Upside deviation is not risk, it's the definition of reward!

So "acceleration" might quantify upside variance per unit of downside variance. I can imagine a momentum strategy using an "acceleration-weighted" allocation scheme. Like riding a rising wave.

This could also be some obscure Greek that I'm not aware of, or have a completely different use. Just wondering. Thanks.

Comment: The gains vs losses idea reminded me of the Omega Ratio https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_ratio . But it is not based on upside variance vs downside variance, so your idea is different.

Comment: This has sent me down a rabbit hole of risk/reward metrics I did not know existed. Really appreciate the link. My issue with the Omega Ratio from the very brief reading I just did is that it's based on Black-Scholles, which also uses standard deviation as the risk measure. But there is obviously a lot more to read about it.

Comment: This may help: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/versions/2.0.4/topics/VolatilitySkewness

Comment: @PolarBear This is literally the thing I described. Thank you! It's volatility skewness huh...I will have to read more into this!

Answer (score 1):

We have used it as a criterion for portfolio selection, for example in [An Empirical Analysis of Alternative Portfolio Selection Criteria](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1365167) and [Risk-Reward Optimisation for Long-Run Investors: An Empirical Analysis](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1694442).
What we found there, however, is that reducing the downside was more important than increasing the upside.

Comment: These papers are oddly and incredibly specific to what I had in mind. Thank you! I've been developing this idea with cryptocurrencies in mind. Technical analysis is rampant in the crypto space and there is so much volatility. I wonder how these methodologies would behave with a portfolio of altcoins.

Comment: A concern for cryptoassets would be liquidity and the
costs of trading. The models described in the papers
worked well when there was a reasonably-large
cross-section of equities to choose from.  The
asymmetric risk functions picked up not only a "low
risk" effect, but also momentum (see
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2975529). The question is whether such effects are at work in cryptoassets as well.